# how to press Enter key in Behat

Tags: behat

I am new to behat and I am stuck in a place where I need to enter texts in a field and then I have to hit enter to add the item to the list.

I am not able to find a solution in Behat. Please help if anyone know about this?

Comment: i have tried to use the below code: $this->getSession()->getDriver()->keyPress($element,13);  But this throws exception:  java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I found the solution in mink document which is quite straightforward. So the answer is:

```
$this->getSession()
      ->getPage()
      ->findById($id_of_field)
      ->keyPress($unicode_of_the_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm correct, you are using extension mink for that?

In that case, you need to checkout [documentation](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/interacting-with-pages.html?highlight=submit).

One of examples:

```
$this->getMinkContext()->pressButton('myid');
```

if you're using others library, the show composer.json and behat.yml files - this should help find solution.